# how to access an element of an n-D matrix where index comes from a mathematical operation

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, indexing

How can I access an element of an n-D matrix where index comes from a mathematical operation in Matlab?

For example I have a 4D Matrix called A.

I want to access element 1,1,1,1 which results from (3,4,5,6) - (2,3,4,5)

Is there any way I can do this assuming that the array can be any dimension **d** and that the array from subtraction will always be **d** elements long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to converting to a cell array, then to a comma-separated list:

```
A = rand(3,4,5,6); % example A
t = [2 1 3 4]; % example index
u = num2cell(t);
result = A(u{:});
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible way would be to utilise the fact that MATLAB can use linear indexing for any n-dimensional array as well as row-column type indexing. Then you just have to calculate the linear index of your operation result.

There may be a more elegant way to do this but if `x` is the array holding the result of your operation, then the following works

`element = A(sum((x-1).*(size(A).^[0:length(size(A))-1]))+1);`

The `sub2ind` function feels like it should help here, but doesn't seem to.

Comment: Nice approach! That was part of the answer I was about to post :-)